# Any reasons why this simple function not working?

Tags: android, sql

I have a simple method.

```
public boolean isUser(String pssword)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql= "select " + USER_NAME + " from  "+ TABLE_USERS + "  where " + PASSWORD + " =" + 
                     " ? ";
        Log.e("sql", sql);
        Log.e("sqlword", pssword);

        db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        String [] args= new String[]{String.valueOf(pssword)};
         Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, args);
         if(c.moveToFirst())
         {
             return true;
         }else
         {
        return false;
         }

    }
```

For testing purposes , i add password as 12.

I run the method, it returns false.

I then open the db using  SQLiteManager and i try

```
select username from  login  where password = '12'
```

No record returned!

I then use

```
select * from  login
```

This time i get that record with password 12.

So really what is the prolem???...

I am puzled!

Comment: Is password a text or an integer field?

Comment: String...i defined the field as text in the table.

Comment: Any additional characters such as spaces or linefeeds in the password field data?

Comment: What do you get when you use select * from login where password = '12'

Comment: he got nothing as he said. So I think the problem is in his database not at his code

Comment: When i try a longer password like 123456 it works....but  why not with 12?....i am still puzzled!

Comment: Try select '[' + password + ']' from login

Comment: You have a large design problem - you shouldn't rely on passwords (or their hashes) being unique.  For that matter, if you're handling passwords properly - using a unique-per-user salt - you have no idea which record to compare to anyways...